# I am not able to mount my external hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, exfat

Recently my laptop which is running on Ubuntu hung while using, so I removed my external hard disk without the "safely remove" option. After that, when I try to mount my external HD it shows 'an operation is already pending'. The error message is

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/keltron/Ashrafz1: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/keltron/Ashrafz1"' exited with non-zero exit status 2:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1'
stderr: `BUG: failed to read 953840 bytes from file at 30539776.'
```

Comment: Possibly relevant Google Groups thread: [BUG: failed to read 524288 bytes from file at 5008523264](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exfat/GV21LgC0-7M). There's a suggestion that it's a hardware fault, so the first recommendation is to look for I/O errors in Dmesg. Personally, I don't know how to do that, so I would run a SMART test instead, but I'm not sure if that's equivalent.

Comment: I didn't understand bro..can u simply things..I am ameture in this..

Comment: See this: [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/528072/301745)